# splitting a string based on tab in the file

Tags: python, string, split

I have file that contains values separated by tab ("\t"). I am trying to create a list and store all values of file in the list. But I get some problem. Here is my code.

```
line = "abc def ghi"
values = line.split("\t")
```

It works fine as long as there is only one tab between each value. But if there is one than one tab then it copies the tab to values as well. In my case mostly the extra tab will be after the last value in the file.

Comment: Are there other whitespace characters in your values that should *not* be split on? Because if not, you could just use `line.split()`, and it would take care of this (as well as discarding empty leading/trailing elements).

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use `regex` here:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "foo\tbar\t\tspam"
>>> re.split(r'\t+', strs)
['foo', 'bar', 'spam']
```

**update:**

You can use  `str.rstrip` to get rid of trailing `'\t'` and then apply regex.

```
>>> yas = "yas\t\tbs\tcda\t\t"
>>> re.split(r'\t+', yas.rstrip('\t'))
['yas', 'bs', 'cda']
```

Comment: Better than my filter approach +1

Comment: but how will it deal if we have the tab in the end of file. It will still take empty value.

Comment: @yasra002 please post an example.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yas = "yas bs cda "
    bbb = re.split(r'\t+', yas) So bb will still have the empty value since there is a tab in the end.

Answer (score 5):

Split on tab, but then remove all blank matches.

```
text = "hi\tthere\t\t\tmy main man"
print([splits for splits in text.split("\t") if splits])
```

Outputs:

```
['hi', 'there', 'my main man']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use regexp to do this:

```
import re
patt = re.compile("[^\t]+")


s = "a\t\tbcde\t\tef"
patt.findall(s)
['a', 'bcde', 'ef']
```

Answer (score 1):

An other `regex`-based solution:

```
>>> strs = "foo\tbar\t\tspam"

>>> r = re.compile(r'([^\t]*)\t*')
>>> r.findall(strs)[:-1]
['foo', 'bar', 'spam']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has support for CSV files in the eponymous [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. It is relatively misnamed since it support much more that just *comma* separated values.

If you need to go beyond basic word splitting you should take a look. Say, for example, because you are in need to deal with *quoted values*...

Comment: Yes, but that still would lead to empty elements.