# Python - Separating by tabs and new lines

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to read a file in Python that looks something like this:

```
hello\t\tsecondhello\n
this\t\tsecondthis\n
is\t\tsecondis\n
data\t\tseconddata\n
```

I'm only interested in the second piece of information for each line, so I'm trying to get rid of those two tabs and the new lines. I tried this:

```
documents = open("data.txt", "r").readlines()
for line in documents:
    splitted = line.strip().split("\t")
    print(splitted)
```

But this only gives me list objects that look like this:

```
['hello\t\tsecondhello']
```

I've also looked at this accepted answer but it gives me the same only that the new lines are kept as well: [splitting a string based on tab in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038426/splitting-a-string-based-on-tab-in-the-file)

EDIT: found the error, it was false formatting in the input file. still, thanks for your help, people

Comment: `line.strip().split("\t\t")`?

Comment: nope, tried that already, getting the exact same output

Comment: I don't get the same result.  I'm using Python 2.7, and I get each line splitting into three fields, as I expect: lines such as ['hello', '', 'secondhello'].  Can you try printing the line and the split string, one character at a time?

Comment: I am using python 3.5 and .split("\t\t") will do the work, .split("\t") gives same result as Prune mentioned.

Comment: splitted = line.strip().split("\t")[2] gives the second value

Comment: the code basically just converts each line into a list object. so the line looks exactly like the list object. it never seems to actually split by tab

Comment: @VaishaliGarg I'm getting an `index out of range` when I try to access it with [2]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your \t are actually escaped and not actual tabs. So try

```
line.strip().split("\\t\\t")
```

Comment: sadly, i'm getting the same result with this

Answer (score 0):

This works with data you provided:

```
data = documents.strip().split('\n')
wanted_data = [item.split('\t')[2] for item in data if item]
```

Comment: Getting this `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'`.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, don't forget [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/345643) it. Thanks.