# how to make a list of a specific column

Tags: python, list, astropy

I have a list of linelists file as below.how do i make a list of only the 3rd column of the output(the one starting with 0.002147)[this is how my output is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNfqe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming linelists looks something like this:

```
l = ['col11\tcol21\tcol31\tcol41\tcol51',
     'col12\tcol22\tcol32\tcol42\tcol52']
```

you can select the third column with

`col3list = [line.split("\t")[2] for line in l]`

which gives you `['col31', 'col32']`.

Based on the image you provided, it is not clear if the columns are separated by a tab or multiple spaces. If the separators are spaces, you would need to change the argument of the split function.

Something similar to your question was also already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946366/python-separating-by-tabs-and-new-lines).

In general I would recommend loading files with the python library [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which can handle all kinds of data loading and selection tasks for you.