# Python create dictionary from a given txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Task: given a txt file with **adjective \t synonym, synonym, synonym, etc.** in a line, several lines are given. I need to create a dictionary, where adjective will be a key and synonyms - a value. My code:

```
#necessary for command-line 
import sys 

#open file for reading
filename = sys.argv[1]
infile = open(filename, "r")

#a
#create a dictionary, where an adjective in a line is a key
#and synonyms are the value
dict = {}

#for each line in filename
for line in filename:
    #key is everything before tab, value - after the tab
    key, value = line.strip().split("\t")
    dict[key.strip()] = value.strip()

#close the file
filename.close()
```

Terminal shows the error:

```
    key, value = line.strip().split("\t")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Could someone help to fix?

Comment: can you post a sample of how the txt file looks like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [splitting a string based on tab in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038426/splitting-a-string-based-on-tab-in-the-file)

Comment: Simple debugging will give you a clue: in your for loop, try `print(line.strip().split("\t"))` and see what you get. It goes along with your "not enough values to unpack" error. Also, I think you mean `for line in infile` not `filename`...

Comment: You're simply having a `line` that doesn't contains a `\t` so the `split` cannot give you 2 members. As suggested by @mansford, if your code is verbatim then you're iterating over the chars of `filename` instead of the lines of `infile`, which would explain that `split` doesn't have much to split in multiple parts.

Answer (score 0):

**filename** is just a string not your file, file is **infile** so you should have
**for line in infile:**
and at the end it's
**infile.close()**
But I think that will still probably not solve your problem, you will get the list as result from the *line.strip().split("\t")*, with two elements though, but the compiler doesn't know how many tabs may be in a line, so you can't unpack it like this.

Comment: Thanks, Brian! Yeah I changed the code how you said, but it still doesn't work :\

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your file handling. You use `filename` as the file object instead of `infile` and if an error is raised, the file won't be closed. Rewrite of your code:

```
#necessary for command-line 
import sys 

#open file for reading
filename = sys.argv[1]

#a
#create a dictionary, where an adjective in a line is a key
#and synonyms are the value
dict = {}

with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    #for each line in infile
    for line in infile:
        #key is everything before tab, value - after the tab
        key, value = line.strip().split("\t")
        dict[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

Comment: Hey Roy, thank you! I fixed that bag but it still doesn't work :((

Comment: @Luiza If you have the same problem (expected 2, got 1), then the problem is probably in your text file.